# How slowly can you clock an AT25DF641A SPI Flash?

Tags: spi, bit-bang

I am have started to try to use a SPI Flash.  To better understand how it works, I decided to try to bit bang it with the GPIO on a Raspberry Pi.  Everything seems correct, but I do not seem to have any output from the SPI Flash.  The clock signal I am sending it is approximately 1 hertz.  As I troubleshoot, I thought I should ask the question:

Is there a limit to how slowly you can interface with an SPI flash?

I am currently using the AT25DF641A-SH-T (1265-1180-1-ND on Digi-Key).

Comment: It can be clocked as slow as you want. Maybe there is an error in the hardware design or software, so better add schematics and code into your question.

Comment: Just as a hint, (and i know this has nothing to do with your question) double check MOSI/MISO and chip select. If your signals look right, there's a high likelihood that either your chip select isn't being set (or is active low and you're sending high), or you reversed MOSI and MISO.

Comment: That flash has a maximum voltage rating of 3.6V.  Is the Raspberry Pi a 5V system???   (I've never used one...)    Did you tie the HOLD pin high??  Are you sure your I/O directions are set correctly ?? (i.e. if you have the flashes SO connected to a pin on the CPU thats also set for OUTPUT, it won't work...)     Many flash devices require you send some startup commands to get them into the right operating mode - Are you doing that????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to check this is in the timing diagram which is in most datasheets with communications specifications. There are no maximum times for \$T_{CLKH}\$ or \$T_{CLKL}\$ which means the SCK can be as long as you want. There are also no maximum restrictions on CS times either so that can be held low or high for as long as you want.

[image]
Source: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/590/doc8693-1385727.pdf

Answer (score 1):

See page 49 of the data sheet, section 14.4. There is no minimum clock frequency listed so you can clock it as slowly as you wish. Take years if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's very rarely a lower limit on speed on SPI devices – they are meant to behave like simple shift registers with attached logic, after all. So, most likely, you're doing something wrong while bitbanging.

Anyway, my guess is that bitbanging was done out of an avoidance of learning how to use the SPI peripheral. Do that!

Comment: Absolutely not!  I am currently in the process of writing a FAT filesystem driver and reading through the specs.  Do not question my desire to learn the most technical things.  Haha.  I suppose trying to use the SPI peripheral will help eliminate where the problem might be.  My 2 guesses is that ether I am writing the OP-Code backwards or the chip is not correctly soldered.

Comment: That's actually pretty cool :)

Comment: If you want a challenge: the datasheet doesn't imply any wear-leveling functionality - that will become a problem with write accesses on a FAT file system. (There's 100,000 program/erase cycles specified – for every single 256 byte page.)

Comment: Unless the SPI flash is going to be shared as block device to computer via USB or somehow, there are better filesystems than FAT for flash chips. Due to 4k block size, it would require 4k cluster size, or manually implementing a layer between FAT and flash chip to provide wear leveling.

Comment: @Justme honest question: I've seen FAT code in microconroller libraries and RTOS'es. It's pretty slim. How complex are these alternatives (thinking about JFFS2, primarily, but I simply don't know what's out there)?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Good question and honest answer: I have used FAT only on media (USB, SD) that needs to be writable by a PCs and readable on MCU - meaning MCU only needs to read a single file on a FAT filesystem on USB stick or SD Card and dump that file directly into somewhere like SPI flash. The SPI flash image could then contain a simpler filesystem-alike headers so MCU can read various different "files". Many tool vendors offer their own filesystems for Flash, e.g. EFS from Keil. And many times the FS on SPI flash is not directly a FAT, but there is a layer to present it as FAT via USB.

Comment: @Justme yeah, a flash transaction layer + FS emulation would probably be the way to go when doing something like a "drop your firmware here" USB mass storage device.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers.  I am posting this for anyone who is curious about what the problem was.

It turns out that my bit-bang interface was fine.  I disconnected everything except for the 3.3V power to the SPI Flash and measured the voltage from the SPI Flash GND pin to power supply ground.  It should have been 3.3V but instead was 0V.  However, I discovered that I could literally push down on the chip with my finger and it would show 3.3V.

I had soldered the SMT chip to an 8-Pin DIP adapter board, but unfortunately, the board was slightly too narrow for the wide chip and it made soldering it difficult.  Under my microscope I couldn't see a gap, but electrically, it was there on some of the pads.  I simply went back over it, adding a lot more soldier to each pad to ensure good electrical contact.  It is now working great!  Thank you for all your help.  I'll have to remember to double check SMT dimensions when ordering parts and adapters.

I'm still very new to electronics and soldering, but I feel like I am making solid progress.  Thanks you again!